# react native redirect to the settings update OS

Tags: react-native, mobile

Hey so i need to check if the user device is older version
if yes i will show alert that tell to update
and if press on button "UPDATE"
i want to take to the screen of the OS to UPDATE.

thanks for anyone who can help!

```
export const CheckOsVersion: FC = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const currentOS = Platform.OS;
        const currentVersion = Number(Platform.Version);

        const LATEST_VERSION_ANDROID = 34;
        const LATEST_VERSION_IOS = 13;
        const MAX_DIFF_VERSION = 2;

        if (currentOS === 'android') {
            if (LATEST_VERSION_ANDROID - currentVersion > MAX_DIFF_VERSION) {
                Alert.alert(
                    'text',
                    '“text.',
                    [
                        {
                            text: 'NOT NOW',
                            onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
                            style: 'cancel',
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Update',
                            onPress: () => console.log('Update Pressed'),
                        },
                    ],
                    { cancelable: false },
                );
            }
        } else if (currentOS === 'ios') {
            if (LATEST_VERSION_IOS - currentVersion > MAX_DIFF_VERSION) {
                Alert.alert(
                    'text',
                    '“text.',
                    [
                        {
                            text: 'NOT NOW',
                            onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
                            style: 'cancel',
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Update',
                            onPress: () => console.log('Update Pressed'),
                        },
                    ],
                    { cancelable: false },
                );
            }
        }
    }, []);
```

Comment: Try import `{ Linking } from 'react-native'`
`Linking.openURL('app-settings:')`

Comment: thanks but this open the app settings. i need the OS  settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the solution that  i found is that you need to write a bridge in native
and use that

something like : [Limk](https://proandroiddev.com/react-native-bridge-with-kotlin-b2afde2f70b)
there is example too here and they explain what is it in Kotlin

that what i did in the
File: SettingsUpdateModule.kt

```
package com.att.fn.android.missioniq.modules.settingsRedirect

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import com.facebook.react.bridge.*


class SettingsUpdateModule(private val reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): ReactContextBaseJavaModule() {

    override fun getName(): String = SettingsUpdateModule::class.java.simpleName

    @ReactMethod
    public  fun  updateOs() {
        val i =Intent("android.settings.SYSTEM_UPDATE_SETTINGS",)
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(this.reactContext, i, null);
    }


}
```